# Creating program for finding minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers

Tags: java

process : 
initial numbers are 1,2,3,4,5 and .

```
If we sum everything except 1, sum is 2+3+4+5=14 .
If we sum everything except 2, sum is 1+3+4+5=13.
If we sum everything except 3, sum is 1+2+4+5=12.
If we sum everything except 4, sum is 1+2+3+5=11.
If we sum everything except 5, sum is 1+2+3+4=10.
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, temp;
        int[] a = new int[5];
        int[] res = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        System.out.print("Enter 5 number");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    res[i] = res[i] + a[j];

                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
                if (res[i] > res[j]) {
                    temp = res[i];
                    res[i] = res[j];
                    res[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(a[0] + " " + a[4]);
    }
}
```

Output: 1 5
Expected Output : 10 14

I have forgotten something in this code. Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Comment: your code doesn't even compile. Remove size `5` from `int[] res = new int[5]{0,0,0,0,0};`. And what is `r` variable here: `res[i] = r;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting Output `1 5` because you're using the contents of the `int a[]` array, when instead you want to use the `int res[]` array, which contains the sorted sums.

Change the last line:
`a[0] + " " + a[4]` to `res[0] + " " + res[4]`